# C with char arrays and indices

Tags: c, string, slice, indices, indic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char data[8];  // "02/08/10"
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &data[i]);
    }
    char DD[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        DD[i] = data[i];
    }
    char MM[2];
    for (int i=3; i<5; i++) {
        MM[i-3] = data[i];
    }
    char AA[2];
    for (int i=6; i<8; i++) {
        AA[i-6] = data[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", DD);  // "0202/08/10"
    printf("%s\n", MM);  // "080202/08/10"
    printf("%s", AA);  // "10080202/08/10"

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted DD to be "02", MM "08" and AA "10". What am I doing wrong?
Here,
DD --> "0202/08/10"
MM --> "080202/08/10"
AA --> "10080202/08/10"

Why??:?

Comment: Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. So need to add 1 char to each array and set the last char to be `'\0'`. Alternatively use `%c` to print each character rather than `%s` which is for NUL terminated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier in `printf` expects the string to be NUL-terminated so it knows when to stop outputting characters. But your arrays are not large enough to terminate the data you're filling them with. When `printf` walks through the string, it runs right off the end of the array and into other memory until it happens to encounter a 0-byte somewhere.

This program therefore has undefined behavior.

Try adding an extra byte to each array and ensure it is zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char data[8] = "02/08/10";
    char DD[3] = {0};
    char MM[3] = {0};
    char AA[3] = {0};

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) DD[i] = data[i];
    for (int i=3; i<5; i++) MM[i-3] = data[i];
    for (int i=6; i<8; i++) AA[i-6] = data[i];

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", DD, MM, AA);
}
```

Alternatively you can tell `printf` to truncate the string to a specific length by specifying `%.2s` (where '2' is the number of characters):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char data[8] = "02/08/10";
    char DD[2], MM[2], AA[2];

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) DD[i] = data[i];
    for (int i=3; i<5; i++) MM[i-3] = data[i];
    for (int i=6; i<8; i++) AA[i-6] = data[i];

    printf("%.2s\n%.2s\n%.2s\n", DD, MM, AA);
}
```

You can also clean up your loops, which are a little messy and prone to mistakes. Look at how much tidier it is with [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char data[8] = "02/08/10";
    char DD[2], MM[2], AA[2];

    memcpy(DD, data, 2);
    memcpy(MM, data+3, 2);
    memcpy(AA, data+6, 2);

    printf("%.2s\n%.2s\n%.2s\n", DD, MM, AA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add a terminator (`\0`) to your `DD,MM,AA`, because `printf` needs to know where to stop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char data[8];  // "02/08/10"
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &data[i]);
    }
    char DD[3];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        DD[i] = data[i];
    }
    DD[2] = '\0';

    char MM[3];
    for (int i=3; i<5; i++) {
        MM[i-3] = data[i];
    }
    MM[2] = '\0';
    
    char AA[3];
    for (int i=6; i<8; i++) {
        AA[i-6] = data[i];
    }
    AA[2] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s\n", DD);  // "0202/08/10"
    printf("%s\n", MM);  // "080202/08/10"
    printf("%s", AA);  // "10080202/08/10"
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
02
08
10
```